# Possible to return a non-string in the form of [[x:y]]?

Tags: python

I am doing a test where the compiler expects printing of `[[1:2], [3:4]]` to the console. Is this output format impossible without formatting to string? I tried formatting each element of the list to a string, eg `['[1:2]', '[3:4]']` but the compiler is rejecting the answer.

Comment: you are printing _what_ exactly to the console?

Comment: The reason for the error is that the [slice syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) (i.e. `[x:y]`) is only allowed within a a subscript of a subscriptable object (e.g. a `list` or a `dict`). For example `my_list[1:2]`. If you write `[1:2]` outside of that context, Python doesn't recognise that. So you may want to create your own slice representation whose repr is that, as shown in the answer by timgeb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reject `print('[[1:2], [3:4]]')` then... technically yes, practically... well.

There is no default Python object with the representation `[y:x]` but you could make one.

```
class WeirdRepr:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'[{self.x}:{self.y}]'


lst = [WeirdRepr(1, 2), WeirdRepr(3, 4)]

print(lst) # [[1:2], [3:4]]
```